# Fatal error: Index out of range after Sign Up (Firebase, Swift)

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, xcode, firebase

I'm trying to learn how to works with Firebase and I've a trouble with arrays after including Firebase in my project ( without Sign Up + Login functionality my code works fine).

I have a `class New` with following structures:

```
class New {


 struct collectViewStruct {
        var image = [UIImage]()
    }

    var collectImageArray = [
        collectionViewStruct(image: [UIImage(named:"maskarad.jpg")!, UIImage(named:"2.jpg")!]),
        collectionViewStruct(image: [UIImage(named:"3.jpg")!, UIImage(named:"4.jpg")!]),
        collectionViewStruct(image: [UIImage(named:"5.jpg")!, UIImage(named:"6.jpg")!])

    ]

    var anImageArray = [
        collectionViewStruct(image: [UIImage(named:"1.jpg")!, UIImage(named:"2.jpg")!, UIImage(named:"3.jpg")!, UIImage(named:"4.jpg")!, UIImage(named:"5.jpg")!]),
        collectionViewStruct(image: [UIImage(named:"3.jpg")!, UIImage(named:"4.jpg")!]),
        collectionViewStruct(image: [UIImage(named:"5.jpg")!, UIImage(named:"6.jpg")!])

    ]

    var detImageArray = [
        collectionViewStruct(image: [UIImage(named:"1.jpg")!, UIImage(named:"2.jpg")!]),
        collectionViewStruct(image: [UIImage(named:"3.jpg")!, UIImage(named:"4.jpg")!]),
        collectionViewStruct(image: [UIImage(named:"5.jpg")!, UIImage(named:"6.jpg")!])
    ]

    struct nVoiceStruct {
        var nVoice = [Int]()
    }

    var vlVoiceArray = [
        nVoiceStruct(nVoice: [0, 1])
    ]

}
```

I have a `CollectionViewController`, where I'm trying to connect data from `CollectionViewController` view to my next `MediaViewController`

```
import UIKit

    var aArray = [UIImage]()
    var dArray = [UIImage]()
    var vArray = [Int]()

    class CollectionViewController: UIViewController, UICollectionViewDataSource, UICollectionViewDelegate {
        var cats : New = New()

         func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

            selectedRow = indexPath.row

            let selectedItemInCategoryArray = cats.anImageArray[selectedRow]
            aArray = selectedItemInCategoryArray.image

            let selectetItemVoice = cats.vlVoiceArray[selectedRow]
            vArray = selectetItemVoice.nVoice


            let selectedItemInArray = cats.collectImageArray[selectedRow]
            dArray = [selectedItemInArray.image[selectedRow]

        }
```

But in my third MediaViewController I have an empty array

```
 aArray[4] = dArray[0]
Thread 1: Fatal error: Index out of range
```

Without Firebase all works, but after Login, I've an empty array. Can't figure out where is a problem. I thought maybe it's because of my variables are outside of class, but when I initialize them inside of class, it doesn't help.I'll be thankful if someone can explain it (names of my classes and variables are just drafts).

Here is log message:

```
2018-03-18 23:03:18.242863+0300 Newapp [Firebase/Analytics] Firebase Analytics started
2018-03-18 23:03:18.243474+0300 Newapp [Firebase/Analytics][I-ACS023008] To enable debug logging set the following application argument: -FIRAnalyticsDebugEnabled (see ...)
2018-03-18 23:03:18.677132+0300 Newapp TIC Read Status [1:0x0]: 1:57
2018-03-18 23:03:18.680586+0300 Newapp TIC Read Status [1:0x0]: 1:57
2018-03-18 23:03:18.938133+0300 Newapp[MC] System group container for systemgroup.com.apple.configurationprofiles path is (here is path)
2018-03-18 23:03:18.941294+0300 Newapp[56497:1489902] [MC] Reading from private effective user settings.
```

Comment: It looks like you are setting `aArray` to have one value in your `didSelectItemAt` function. I'm also wondering how do you go from your collectionView to the MediaViewController? Where is that code?

Comment: @Jake I go from collectionView to `MediaViewController` through `didSelectItemAt` and `segue` without code(using storyboard), I've collection view (categories of pets), on next `MediaViewController` I'm trying replace one element of array to another, but after I did include Firebase, all arrays (`aArray, vArray, dArray`) are empty. When I'm deleting FirebaseAuth code, all another code works again

Comment: @Jake Here are my files [link](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/9744edc70b06fccda1224eba9fa0173f)

Comment: add this code to your MediaViewController viewDidLoad and comment out everything else you have `if let testArray = aArray { print(aArray) } else { print("aArray is nil") }` Let me know what prints

Comment: @Jake it doesn't print anything, console is empty, just lldb and `Fatal error: Index out of range`. When I deleted `OS_ACTIVITY_MODE` from Environment Variables, I got this message on console `Reading from private effective user settings`

Comment: Will you edit your question to include the entire error log that prints? And  does it crash on launch or does it  crash on segue to `MediaViewController`?

Comment: That edit doesn't show the fatal error. You copied and pasted the entire console after crash?

Comment: @Jake Yes , I added the entire log prints to this question. It crushs only on segue  `MediaViewController`. Before I did implement Firebase Login, code worked. When I implemented Firebase Login, Login Screen works, first screen (`ViewController`) after login works, one segue works from first `ViewController` to `CollectionViewController`, but  next segue from `CollectionViewController` to `MediaViewController` doesn't works

Answer (score 1):

I tried to make these steps:

1. Go to my `Main.storyboard`
2. Choose my `MediaViewController` -> `Editor` - > `Embeded in Navigation Controller`

and it solved the problem